# How can I count values (except duplicates)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, count

How can I count value in column (except duplicates). I try this code but I didn't. Thanks for helping. (Sorry my bad English)

```
long net = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "select date, count(*) from  mytable GROUP BY date", null);
nettext.setText(String.valueOf(net));     

For example:
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2006-10-08 |
|  2 | 2006-10-08 |
|  3 | 2006-10-09 |
+----+------------+

There is two different date (2006-10-08 and 2006-10-09)
Result must be = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution this like. Thanks m.aibin.

```
long net = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "select count(DISTINCT date) from  mytable", null);
```

Answer (score 3):

That should work:

```
long net = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "select count(DISTINCT date) from  mytable GROUP BY date", null);
```